# Change item style

Tags: enumerate

I'm using:

```
\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=!, labelindent=0pt]
        \item
    \end{enumerate}
```

How can I change the style for the items? Something like other type of enumeration, bold numbers, etc?

Answer (score 4):

Use the package `enumitem` (documentation [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en)).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*}] %Your options go in the label= tag
\item I'm first
\item I'm second
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\Roman*}]
    \item Now I'm first.
    \item And I'm second.
    \end{enumerate}
\item But I'm the only third.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit:

You can also change individual labels like so:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item I'm first.
\item I'm second.
\item[\refstepcounter{enumi}\textbf{\alph{enumi}.}] I'm different.
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this using the package enumerate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[a]   %%give the sample model here
    \item first item with lowercase alphabet
 \begin{enumerate}[i]  %%for lower case roman
    \item first item with lower case roman numbering
     \item second item with lower case roman numbering
\end{enumerate}
  \item first item with lowercase alphabet
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[7.1]  %% for decimal numbered items starting from 7.1
   \item numbered first item
   \item numbered second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You can add period, parenthesis, \bf, \it, \sf, \sc etc. in the optional bracket too!

[image]

Comment: `\bf` etc. are obselete...